# How to use time.sleep() within a function correctly?

Tags: python

Long story short i am making an rpg game (text based) in python and need a little help. I am using the time library to give a delay between certain ASCII banners popping up in the console. However, i dont want to have to write out 'time.sleep()' or copy and paste it every time i want to use it. Therefore, i made a function which I would use to shorten the time it would take me to right out 'time.sleep()':

```
def wait(time):

    time.sleep(time)

wait(1)
```

Whilst in theory i thought this would work (im new to python, i have much to learn yet), it gives me this error:

```
    time.sleep(time)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

I was wondering if anyone could help/point me in the right direction on how to go about this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try renaming your variable time in sth like timer --> your passing it to both the function and the variable..

Comment: Inside that function, `time` refers to the parameter of the function, *not* the module which you presumably imported earlier.  Choose a different name for the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same name for the module and the function parameter, so the parameter (a local variable) is shadowing the module (a global variable). Change the parameter:

```
def wait(how_long):
     time.sleep(how_long)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different name for your parameter, so it doesn't hide the namespace within your function:

```
def wait(period):
    time.sleep(period)
```

Or you could eliminate your function altogether by importing `sleep` under a different name:

```
from time import sleep as wait
```